# Printing Word document directly

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, word, printing

is it possible to print a word document directly from the document libary? 
This must be done witout opening word on the local machine.

Is it only possible wit a custom ribbon with JavaScript in it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a Word document, Word must be opened one way or the other. Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but you can open the document library in Explorer, then right-click the Word document(s) and select Print from the context menu. This will open Word, perform the print operation (to the default printer) and close Word again.

Comment: yes your are right, that is not exactly for what I looking for. So if I have Office Web Apps installed. Do you think that it is possible to perform a automation that the document will be opened in the browser and after that it will perform a click on print?